# Foreground service is stopped when app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to run a background custom process with a foreground notification in ionic 5. The aim is to run the background process when the app is open, minimized, terminated.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/foreground-service

I tried this plugin and started and stopped the foreground service.

```
this.foregroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service', 'drawable/fsicon');

this.foregroundService.stop();
```

but when the app goes to the background and if the user tries to close all open apps then the foreground service is also stopped.

I am trying to replicate how WhatsApp web runs. The WhatsApp web notification runs on the device and communicates with the browser even if the app is closed.

So I need some pointers or any other approach to implement run my custom process even if the app is terminated by a user.

Comment: Implementing a reliable foreground service is always a pain. There are many pitfalls, but in my experience it is in the end a matter of RTFM: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Read the whole thing carefully and takes notes and I am pretty sure you will reach your goal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I am looking to achieve it through hybrid app and wanted to avoid native change unless must

Comment: ah, I read over the ionic part, sorry! Unfortunately, I have no experience with ionic :(